# .click() does nothing on debian vps selenium phantomjs

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I need to click on a button that is submitting a form, using selenium and phantomjs webdriver.

I currently have the following code that is working great on my local computer (under archlinux)

```
driver.find_element_by_id("lbc_submit").click()
```

Before calling this code i ensure that the element i click on is present with selenium expected condition.

When i execute the same code with the same webdriver (both same version) on a debian vps server the element is present as i have no exception when i click on it but nothing is happening.

Here is the html of the input (inside a form) :

```
<input class="button-blue" value="Valider mon annonce" name="create" id="lbc_submit" type="submit">
```

I tried the following but none of that works :

- Clicking using javascript
- Submitting using javascript
- Change phantomjs webdriver to chrome webdriver
- Wait with a sleep before clicking to ensure everything is loaded
- Using .submit() selenium method

**Edit - more information**

Here is the pastebin to the entire form where the button i click is (line 172):

https://pastebin.com/ehax7mkQ

My code block :

```
def validate_ad(browser):
    if not adbot_utils.get_page(browser, "", By.ID, "lbc_submit"):
        return false
    browser.find_element_by_id("lbc_submit").click()
    return true
```

get_page function :

```
def get_page(browser, url, by_method, element_path):
    if url:
        browser.get(url)
    try:     
        WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((by_method, element_path)))
    except TimeoutException:
        if url:
            print_log("Failed to load page " + url, 0, __name__)
        else:
            print_log("Failed to load element [" + element_path + "]", __name__)
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: Add URL or HTML
Please

Comment: I edited my post with the html of the button i click on

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
driver.find_element_by_id("lbc_submit").click()
```

Try :

- **`xpath`**

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='button-blue' and @id='lbc_submit']").click()
  ```
- **`css_selector`**

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.button-blue#lbc_submit").click()
  ```

Comment: @Epoch Show us more of outerHTML and your code block please

Comment: Edited with the html of the form containing my button and the code block